# MySQL on PowerPC 64

Tags: mysql, operating-system, powerpc

I have a web application which uses Mysql 5.6  as db. The application runs fast in x64 systems. But we have to install this application on PowerPC 64 bit machine for a client. The problem is that application runs fast on x64 and about 7 times slow on RHEL 6 in PowerPC 64 bit machine. The time difference is mainly due to Mysql performance in different machines.
Since Mysql does not provide binaries for PowerPCs, I have compiled Mysql from source for PowerPcs.

1. Why is Mysql 5.6 running slow on PowerPC 64 bit?
2. Will there be any improvement if AIX OS is used instead of RHEL?
3. How can I improve performance of MySql 5.6 in PowerPC 64 bit?
4. Will there be any improvement if MySql 5.1 or some lower version of Mysql is used?

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: In my case, I found that disk access with mysql 5.6 on power pc is extremely slow as compared to x64. I have added indexes for most frequent queries after which the performance in power pc is comparable to x64. Performance of 5.1 for powerpc provided by mysql was almost equal to that of mysql 5.6 built from source with default configurations

Answer (score 0):

You are building from source without explicit optimizations for `PowerPC`.

You may have better luck using the optimizations tested here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39630
These were done on `MySql 5.1` but most should work fine for `5.6` as well. If not, downgrading to `MySql 5.1` will probably have more tested optimizations for `PowerPC`